# htaccess routing that affects specific directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to place an `.htaccess` file into a specific directory (e.g. `/mydir`) so that instead of writing an URL like this:

`www.example.com/mydir/file.php?x=hey&y=ben` you can write this:
`www.example.com/mydir/hey/ben`.

The routing must affect only the URLs that start with `www.example.com/mydir` while being able at the same time to write URLs like this: `www.example.com/anotherdir/test.php`.

I tried below rules to apply this to all URLs (I've put that in the main root)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

but I don't know how to make it for a sub-directory.

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve your desired result?  What was the actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `.htaccess` in `/mydir/, you can use this first rule in your **root**`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=([^&]+)&y=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydir/file\.php$ /mydir/%1/%2 [NC,L,R=302,QSD]
```

Try it in a fresh browser in incognito mode.